# What is back pressure on stream processing?

Tags: node.js, stream, pipe, backpressure

I started learning NodeJS, and streams seems to be something that people use a lot. In most of the documentation that I had read there are mentions of the "back-pressure problem" that occurs when you are processing big sized files but I haven't found a clear explanation of what exactly this problem is. Also I have read that using pipes can help with this problem, but how exactly do pipes fix the back-pressure problem?

Thanks for any explanation in advance.

Comment: Imagine you had something like `readStream.pipe(writeStream)`. Back pressure is when the `writeStream` is unable to consume the data as quickly as the `readStream` is pushing data to it. [This article](https://howtonode.org/streams-explained) does a decent job of explaining the issue and how you might handle it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that article was really helpful.

Comment: @idbehold, link doesn't work.Do you have other link?

Comment: @Mandroid https://github.com/creationix/howtonode.org/blob/master/articles/streams-explained.markdown

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Comment: The link is also archived: https://archive.is/KZabP

Answer (score 7):

Backpressure is when you write to a stream faster than the other process can handle/consume
Using Pipes, you can control the flow, pause and resume the stream;
Here is an example implementing backpressure in nodejs

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  var file = fs.createWriteStream('upload.jpg'),
      fileBytes = request.headers['content-length'],
      uploadedBytes = 0;

  request.on('data', function(chunk) {
    uploadedBytes += chunk.length;
    var progress = (uploadedBytes / fileBytes) * 100;
    response.write('progress: ' + parseInt(progress, 10) + '%\n');

    var bufferOK = file.write(chunk);

    if (!bufferOK) {
      request.pause();
    }
  });

  file.on('drain', function() {
    request.resume();
  });

  request.on('end', function() {
    response.end('upload complete\n');
  });

});

server.listen(8080);
```

Ben foster solution - Souce: https://gist.github.com/benfoster/9543337

Comment: how does client must react on pausing channel? can it continue throwing away requests assuming underlying transport system controls everything (actually not cause somewhere is limited buffer/queue)?