# How to customize Stream transform to parse stream array json

Tags: node.js, json, parsing, stream

How to implement a customized stream transform to handle multiple chunks and parse out the individual JSON object.

I know that we have an option to use 3rd party library [stream-json](https://github.com/uhop/stream-json), but I would like write own method. Looking for some expertise. THank you in advance.

Input file, users.json

```
[{
    "name": "Jo{hn Doe",
    "occupation": "gardener",
    "born": "1992-03-02"
  }
  ,
  {
    "name": "Brian Flemming",
    "occupation": "teacher",
    "born": "1967-11-22"
  }
  ,
  {
    "name": "Lucy }Black",
    "occupation": "accountant",
    "born": "1995-04-07"
  }
  ,
  {
    "name": "William Bean",
    "occupation": "pilot",
    "born": "1977-10-31"
  }]
```

Possible way to use customized [stream transform](https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/#ts-model)

```
async function main() {
  const readStream = fs.createReadStream('users.json', {highWaterMark: 120 })
  await util.promisify(stream.pipeline)(
    readStream,
    customizedTransform,
    async function( parsedArrayEntriesIterable ){
      for await (const {key: arrIndex, value: arrElem} of parsedArrayEntriesIterable) {
        console.log("Parsed array element:", arrElem);
      }
    }
  )
}
main()
```

expect

```
Parsed array element: { name: 'Jo{hn Doe', occupation: 'gardener', born: '1992-03-02' }
Parsed array element: { name: 'Brian Flemming', occupation: 'teacher', born: '1967-11-22' }
Parsed array element: { name: 'Lucy }Black', occupation: 'accountant', born: '1995-04-07' }
Parsed array element: { name: 'William Bean', occupation: 'pilot', born: '1977-10-31' }
```

Comment: Is this a question of how to extend the `stream.Transform` class to write a custom transformer or are you asking how to write a JSON parser?